# I want to parse string as date using DateTimeFormatter with in "MMdd" but it is even parsing string like "3212" which is wrong

Tags: java, datetime-format, string-to-datetime

```
DateTimeFormatter dateTimeFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMdd");
dateTimeFormatter.parse("3212");
```

Comment: @OleV.V. I believe you should be able to reopen the question...

Comment: Danke schön, @Carlos, for the suggestion. I was aware that I could but wanted to give you a chance to argue against me before doing so, also because this question already had an accepted answer, so I didn’t consider it urgent. Thx for reopening the question. (Kommentar in Baden verfasst)

Comment: @OleV.V. Kein Problem (aus Weilimdorf) that sure was a *nicer way* to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to get the error message you expect, you need to parse into a datetime object of an appropriate sort. Your code is parsing the string only, not trying to interpret it. So it is not discovered that there is no 32nd month. Try for example:

```
    dateTimeFormatter.parse("3212", MonthDay::from);
```

This yields:

> Exception in thread "main" java.time.format.DateTimeParseException:
>   Text '3212' could not be parsed: Unable to obtain MonthDay from
>   TemporalAccessor: {MonthOfYear=32, DayOfMonth=12},ISO of type
>   java.time.format.Parsed

**Why is this so?** Java perceives your formatter as independent of a particular calendar system or chronology. You may check that `dateTimeFormatter.getChronology()` returns `null`. As Arnaud Denoyelle notes in [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51822257/i-want-to-parse-string-as-date-using-datetimeformatter-with-in-mmdd-but-it-is/51822478#comment90599187_51822478), the one-arg `DateTimeFormatter.parse` method that you called returns a `TemporalAccessor`. The documentation of `TemporalAccessor` says:

> implementations of this interface may be in calendar systems other
>   than ISO.

Some calendar systems have 13 months (in some years). Rather than setting an arbitrary limit on month number (13? 14? 15?) it has been decided to leave this to the concrete date and time classes that you normally use for holding your data. The `MonthDay` class that I use represents a “month-day in the ISO-8601 calendar system”, in which a year always has 12 months, so now we get the expected exception.

Comment: Seems legit according to the javadoc about [TemporalAccessor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/temporal/TemporalAccessor.html) (which is the result type of `dateTimeFormatter.parse(...)`): "There are many reasons for this, part of which is that implementations of this interface may be in calendar systems other than ISO.". I don't have enough knowledge about that to upvote though.